# User state management based on Google account

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I am developing an Android application to solve operational research problems. Right now it has a free mode and a paid pro mode using google play in-app purchases. Pro mode allows a user to solve problems of any dimension and using any method available in the app.

Now there is a following problem, which I don't know how to solve best:
I want to provide each user an ability to solve any kind of problem 3 times without paying when a user first installed the app. I'd like to somehow link it to a google account, so the state will be single across different devices with the same account. Good bonus would be if a user should not explicitly log in to the account in the app itself to identify.

What is the best way to do it? I'll need a backend server I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking of two ways, the easy one and the right one:

1. The Easy one: you could use google play games services, which lets you store users game data without any backend. This is not the right way because what you are developing isn't really a game, thus when the user is prompted to sign in to google play games account will seem strange...
2. The right one: implement a google sign-in process and store your information on a database. I suggest you to use google's firebase which is free for limited usage and very easy to integrate. It offers an easy way to implement google sign-in procedure and a really cool database called firestore